# error using breqn : Double subscript \mathsub

Tags: math-mode, breqn

I changed to using 2 columns, and many equations do not fit any more. I heard about breqn package, so I am trying to see if it will help.

Using breqn package on auto-generated code, which compiles OK with `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}`

I am getting an error which I do not understand. MWE is below. Please note the line of code here is auto-generated. So I kept it as is. There was other lines, but kept the one giving the error

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
q^{\prime}(t) &= \operatorname{Re}\left(  \overset{\hat{B}}{\overbrace{\left(  \omega_{n}q_{0}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}+q_{0}^{\prime}\right)  }}e^{i\omega_{n}t}\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While this gives the error. I used `dmath` and removed the `&`, that is all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
q^{\prime}(t) = \operatorname{Re}\left(  \overset{\hat{B}}{\overbrace{\left(  \omega_{n}q_{0}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}+q_{0}^{\prime}\right)  }}e^{i\omega_{n}t}\right)

\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

error

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
! Double subscript.
<recently read> \mathsub 

l.9 ...^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}+q_{0}^{\prime}\right)  }}
                                                  e^{i\omega_{n}t}\right)
?
```

**question:**
What do I need to fix the above so I can use breqn? Using Tex Live 2012 debian package on Linux mint.

Comment: Your combination of `\overset{<top>}{\overbrace{..}}` is causing a problem. The correct way to use it would be `\overbrace{..}^{<top>}`. Another problem is the empty/blank line which is prohibited (it doesn't appear in the first `align` example).

Comment: @Werner thanks. That fixed the error. Strange that it still worked the way it was. The code was autogenerated. If you would like to post that as an answer so it an be accepted. But now since the whole document is compiled with breqn used in few places, I see many large empty vertical spaces between many things which were not there before. I might have to make a new question on that if I can't figure it myself. But breqn did good job on breaking those long equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your combination of `\overset{<top>}{\overbrace{..}}` is causing a problem. The correct way to use it would be `\overbrace{..}^{<top>}`. I assume this is due to the way `\overset` is constructing its argument and accent placement.

Another problem is the empty/blank line which is prohibited (it doesn't appear in the first align example).