# Why does adding \usepackage{breqn}, even if not used, cause LaTeX compile errors in some places?

Tags: breqn

I have many LaTeX files that includes a common .tex file which has the preamble code.

In this include file I added, at the end, this

```
\usepackage{breqn}
```

and then run make to build the whole tree. I see now new errors showing in files which compiled ok before.

One example was this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119251/error-using-breqn-double-subscript-mathsub)

Another example is below. The LaTeX code is auto-generated by SWP.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{breqn}  %uncomment this to see the error
\begin{document}
\[
\left(  X\circledast Y\right)  \circledast W={\displaystyle\sum\limits_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}}\left(  \overset{\left(  X\circledast Y\right)  \left(  l\right)}{\overbrace{{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}}X\left(  k\right)  Y\left(  l-k\right)  }}\right)  W\left(  n-l\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

uncommenting `\usepackage{breqn}` in the above, gives the error

```
>pdflatex foo.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
<argument> {\displaystyle \sum \limits 
                                       _{k=-\infty }^{\infty }}X\left ( k\ri...
l.8 ...}X\left(  k\right)  Y\left(  l-k\right)  }}
                                                  \right)  W\left(  n-l\right)
?
```

I'd like to just understand what is going to help in managing this. I see the error message above, but if the LaTeX code was invalid, then how could it have compiled OK before adding breqn?  Why is adding `breqn` causes some compile errors in some places that did not exist before?

Using TexLive 2012 debian original package. No changes/addition to it made on my Linux box.

Comment: `breqn` changes *many* things; mixing `amsmath` environments with `breqn` ones is not recommendable. Take or leave. I leave.

Comment: @egreg You mean one can't use `\[ ... \]` if they include the breqn package? I am trying to understand what you mean by mixing. I am newbie in Latex. thanks.

Comment: If you use `breqn`, then do what the package wants. No `\[...\]`, `align`, `gather` and so on. No `\limits` either. I find the deficiences of `breqn` much superior to its benefits, but it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `breqn` package changes the definition of `\sum` (and of almost all other commands for math mode). The definition it uses is (using the output of `\show`)

```
> \sum=\protected\long macro:
->\@sym \sum \math_sym_COs:Nn \mg@cop {50}.
```

The macro `\@sym` is the same as `\@gobble`, at least between `\[` and `\]`, so the first two tokens disappear. Now TeX finds `\math_sym_COs:Nn`

```
> \math_sym_COs:Nn=\long macro:
->\math_bsym_COs:Nn .
```

Uhm. Let's see `\math_bsym_COs:Nn`

```
> \math_bsym_COs:Nn=\long macro:
#1#2->\math_char:NNn 1#1{#2}\sumlimits .
```

So the tokens `\mg@cop` and `{50}` are the second and third arguments to `\math_char:NNn`

```
> \math_char:NNn=\protected\long macro:
#1#2#3->\tex_mathchar:D \__int_eval:w "#1#2#3\__int_eval_end: .
```

This simply produces

```
\mathchar"1350
```

because `\mg@cop` expands to `3` (the number of the math extension font family). So the symbol is produced, but there's `\sumlimits` after it

```
> \sumlimits=\displaylimits.
```

Wait! This means that `\sum\limits` should be legal!

Indeed it is. But in some situations `\@sym` is *not* equivalent to `\@gobble` (and this is the reason why it's there). When the second argument to `\overset` is being processed, `\@sym` becomes equivalent to `\binrel@sym`

```
\def\binrel@sym#1#2#3#4{%
  \xdef\binrel@@##1{%
    \ifx\math_sym_Ord:Nn #2 \math_csym_Ord:Nn
    \else\ifx\math_sym_Var:Nn#2 \math_csym_Var:Nn
    \else\ifx\math_sym_COs:Nn#2 \math_csym_COs:Nn
    \else\ifx\math_sym_COi:Nn#2 \math_csym_COi:Nn
    \else\ifx\math_sym_Bin:Nn#2 \math_csym_Bin:Nn
    \else\ifx\math_sym_Rel:Nn#2 \math_csym_Rel:Nn
    \else\ifx\math_sym_Pun:Nn#2 \math_csym_Pun:Nn
    \else\exp_not:N\@symErr \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  ?{\exp_not:N\OrdSymbol{##1}}}%
}
```

This is the cause of the error: `\limits` comes after *nothing*, because one of the workings of `\overset` is to examine its second argument in order to apply the correct spacing around the whole construction. Here `breqn` (more precisely `flexisym.sty`) tries to be clever and does a different test than `amsmath`. The failure is here: when `\@sym` is redefined, it absorbs four arguments using only the second one (`\sum` itself). And `\limits` remains alone in the input stream.

A minimal example showing the failure is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}  %uncomment this to see the error
\begin{document}
\[
\overset{X}{\sum\limits_0}
\]
\end{document}
```

The (wrong) assumption made by `flexisym` is that the second argument of `\overset` contains a single token.

Comment: If you want to defy `breqn`'s cleverness, use good old `\stackrel`, with a surrounding pair of braces.

Answer (score 7):

To put stuff above an `\overbrace` simply use the construction `\overbrace{-bottom-}^{-top-}`, which works fine with `breqn`.

Your construction `\overset{-top-}{\overbrace{-bottom-}}` is an abuse of `\overset`, which as far as I can tell is meant for stacking single symbols or relations.  Here you pile a whole formula atop another.  One way around the error which `egreg` details is to save the primitive `\let\orig@limits\limits` and redefine `\def\limits{\ifx\@sym\binrel@sym\else \orig@limits \fi}`, so as to only call the primitive when in a normal mode.  Alas! there is still a second error `Limit controls must follow a math operator`.  And nothing can save us so easily, because this time `\sum` is really not typeset as an operator.  Why?  Well, `breqn` tries to find out what symbols you are trying to pile with `\overset`.  It turns out that the last atom in the math list for the bottom is an ordinary symbol, so `breqn` considers the whole bottom stuff as a single ordinary symbol: everything in there is treated like ordinary symbols (`\mathord`).  In particular the `\sum` becomes `\mathord{\sum}`, and that does not accept `\limits` controls.

Document that works:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(  X\circledast Y\right)  \circledast W
={\displaystyle
\sum\limits_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}} \left(
\overbrace{
  {\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}}X
  \left(  k\right)  Y\left(  l-k\right)
}^{
  \left(  X\circledast Y\right)
  \left(  l\right)}
\right)
W\left(  n-l\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

There are problems with `breqn` but this ain't one.